# Fastest and most lightweight menu approach for creating a multi level menu

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create a menu like [this one](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/multi_level_drop_down_menu/?st#) and the performance is very important factor for me.
So far I've encountered two different approaches, Javascript and CSS and I'm having a hard time figuring out which way I should go. Which one is faster and more lightweight approach?

My website works with Javascript but the one thing I'm curious about is that if I choose the CSS approach, can I somehow make it work in a way that if the user has Javascript disabled, a static page shows to him/her?

I'll explain my question with an example. Suppose I have a `DOWNLOAD` button on my menu. If user has JS, the download content should appear on the same page with the aid of jQuery but if the user has JS disabled, clicking on the menu item should take the user to `download.php` page.

By the way, if there is a free solution of the approach you suggest, please provide a link to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS menus are harder to use than JS ones: a sub-menu will instantly hide if the mouse is 1px off even 1ms long. You can add 100 or 200ms delay on JS menus and allow small movement mistakes from your visitors. Not everybody is a gamer with perfect mouse skills ;)

So-called "mega dropdown" menus are maybe better than the example you provided. Going vertically and then horizontally is hard on the web (and even on desktop it's only used for seldomly accessed functions in software. Only us webdevelopers and webdesigners go through these complicated menus with ease :) ); mega dropdown will display the whole links with nice headings to the visitor.

You'll maybe also want to consider menus that display submenus on click (i.e. after the user clicked on a main link) if your site should be easy to use on smartphones.

EDIT:
I should've added these links without you asking about them, but couldn't find the second one (now it's in my bookmarks, thanks :))

- Jakob Nielsen (usability guru) about dropdown menus: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/mega-dropdown-menus.html here
- [Why Hover Menus Do Users More Harm Than Good](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-hover-menus-do-users-more-harm-than-good/)
- Design pattern: [Vertical Dropdown Menu](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/VerticalDropdownMenu)

Comment: Could you please provide me a link or a simple example? I'm a little new to the web world.

Comment: Sure, I've added 3 relevant links

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the best approach is to combine this method with the one presented in a few other answers (like psr's).

Comment: @Felipe Alsacreations -  surprising that i don't actually see any recommendations for actually code or jquery plugins in all of these examples

Answer (score 1):

You could use a css based menu that starts out displayed, then use JS to hide it as quickly as possible.  Or you could even replace it with another menu style that relies on JS.

CSS is faster and lighter weight .  JS is more flexible.  Hybrid is heaviest weight.

Comment: Well, this is kind of mentioned in my question itself. But my question is, which approach is faster/better and whether or not I can use a hybrid method (that supports both JS-enabled and disabled clients)

Comment: @AlirezaNoori - I'm saying you can do a hybrid by using a pure CSS method.  Then use javascript to hide the pure CSS method and implement the JS method.  That works in both cases.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a quick example?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori - A reasonable request, but I can't now.  Not sure I'll end up getting to it in any reasonable time either.  If I'm not showered with up votes for the answer I'll understand.

Answer (score 1):

A good reason to learn about [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). Use both CSS and JS!

You should create a functioning basic CSS menu for that very small percentage of people that don't use javascript and then build on it with JS to get what you want.

Not only is it good for accessibility, it will create stronger more bug free code as you are guaranteed to fall back to something functioning (most of the time)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use pure css to achieve the affect you are looking for. This way you do not have to rely on having js enabled. about 30-50% of users browse the web with no js enabled until they need it, at least from my experience and sites I maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should hide the child submenus by default, and each of the top level items should link to a page that allows me access to the items that would normally be in that menu.

For example, if you had a menu item called `Cats` and the children items are various breeds of Cats, then your top level page (/cats/) should have links to the breeds as well.

In short: The top level menu should ideally link to an index of what is in the child menu. This way, someone who clicks on the menu will still get access to the contents of the menu, regardless of if they have Javascript or not (or are using an iPad which is quirky with menus and the like)